# Traveling internationally (outside US) during pending J1 transfer

Tags: usa, visa

Due to the COVID-19 lockdown, I am currently outside of the US, but still work for my US institution. I find conflicting information regarding the possibility to do a J1-transfer, while being outside of the US.

**Is it possible to transfer a J1 visa while being outside of the US?**

View 1:
https://ap.washington.edu/ahr/visas/j1/transfer/

> If an Exchange Visitor leaves the US then seeks to return under the sponsorship of a new exchange visitor program, this would be viewed as a “new entry,” not a “transfer,” and therefore all the rules and procedures for beginning a new program would apply including possible bars on repeat participation in J-1 status.

View 2 (possible, but discouraged):
https://isso.ucsf.edu/j-1-program-transfer

> Exiting and Re-Entering the U.S. while transfer is pending
> While the transfer is pending, travel outside the USA is STRONGLY DISCOURAGED. If emergency travel is necessary, consult ISSO immediately for assistance.

**Thank you for your help!**